# define image as newcommand

Tags: latex

I'm trying to set a image (Canadian flag) as a command in my latex résumé project. I am a beginner in latex and I'm trying to replicate another command definition based on fontawesome package (pre-define images), but by integrating an image.

Here's the original command that works (faAt comes from fontawesome package):

```
\newcommand{\emailsymbol}{\faAt}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\printinfo{\emailsymbol}{#1}}
```

Here's my try that doesn't work:

```
\newcommand{\canflag}{\def\@canada.png}
\newcommand{\canadaflag}[1]{\printinfo{\canflag}{#1}}
```

Any idea on how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `graphicx` package to achieve this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\canadaflag{\includegraphics[height=8pt]{flag}}

\begin{document}
    \section{Before you start}
    \canadaflag You are now using...
\end{document}
```

[image]